# Event copy/paste on mouse position

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse-position

I am trying to copy/paste the block on the mouse position but it pastes on (0,0) position each time

```
    $(document).keydown(function(e){ 
      if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = true;
      if (ctrlDown && e.keyCode == cKey) { 
        copyblockTypes = selectedList.map(block => block.blockType)
      };
      if (ctrlDown && (e.keyCode == vKey)) {
        for (const block of copyblockTypes) {
          console.log($('#'+block).parent().clone()) 
        }
        for (const block of copyblockTypes) {
            newDraggable(
                $('#'+block).parent().clone(),
                { top: e.pageY + 'px',
                left: e.pageX + 'px' }, 
                true,
                0
              );
       
          }
          correctPosition(block);
        }
    }).keyup(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == ctrlKey || e.keyCode == cmdKey) ctrlDown = false;
        }
      )
     

  });
```

And when I am checking in my console left & top are not at the same position I don't know if it is a big deal (see image bellow)

[caracteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tusxl.png)

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be reinventing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent does not have page properties. You would need to use mouse movements and log it from there.

Comment: What were the values of `e.pageY` and `e.pageX` when you debugged them inside the keyboard event handler?

Answer (score 0):

Key Event does not have x and y position. So you would need to add a mouse move event to get it.

```js
(function() {

  let x;
  let y;

  document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.key === 'v') {
      console.log('keydown', x, y);
    }
  });

  window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
    x = evt.pageX;
    y = evt.pageY;
  });

}());
```